# Print lines where first column matches, second column different

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

In a text file, how do I print out only the lines where the first column is duplicate but 2nd column is different?  I want to reconcile these differences.  Possibly using awk/sed/bash?

Input:

```
Jon    AAA
Jon    BBB
Ellen  CCC
Ellen  CCC
```

Output:

```
Jon  AAA
Jon  BBB
```

**Note** that the real file is not sorted.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are the entries always grouped as in your example?

Comment: No, mixed and random

Comment: Are there ever more than two lines with the same value in column one? If so, what should happen?

Comment: @user1899415 could there more than 2 lines that have same col1 and diff col2? what about there was another line `Jon AAA`? what would be the output then

Comment: output would still be the same. I just want to print out the lines that have a difference in col2 for the duplicates in col1 to reconcile these differences.

Comment: Don't put important information in comments, put it in your question, ad make sure your sample input represents the difficult scenarios of your real input. In this case mix it up!

Comment: What if you have a 3rd line `Jon AAA`? SHould it be printed or not or can that just not happen to have more than 2 instances of a key?

Answer (score 1):

this line should do: (I broke the one-liner into 3 lines for better reading)

```
awk '!($1 in a) {a[$1]=$2;next}
     $1 in a && $2!=a[$1]{p[$1 FS $2];p[$1 FS a[$1]]}
     END{for(x in p)print x}' file
```

- the 1st line save $1 $2 into array, if it was checked first time
- line2: for existing $1 and different $2, put them (the two lines) into an array `p`, so that same $1,$2 combination won't be print multiple times.
- print the index of array `p`

Comment: This rearranges the order in the output. Not sure if that's a problem or not.

Comment: no, this doesn't keep the order of occurrence @TomFenech. we could make it, but it needs more checkings also need another array to save the order info.

Comment: @Kent Good solution, though it is not clear what OP wants. For example, if you introduce a line say `Jon   AAA` at the end, it will still print that line even though the line is a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

```
sort file | uniq -u
```

Will only print the unique lines.

Comment: You can remove the `sort` and simply use: `uniq -u file` unless you have some need to sort.

Comment: I doubt if this  is OP wanted. say if in his example there is another line:`FOO BAR`, your uniq will bring it into output. but from my understanding, he might not want that line.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, in a prior comment, the OP said that the lines would be "mixed and random", thus the sort.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
sort file | uniq -u | rev | uniq -Df1 | rev
```

This sorts the file, removes any duplicate lines, reverses the line, removes and unique lines that don't have the same key (keeps duplicates where the 2nd field is the same) and the reverses the line to its original position.

This will drop duplicate lines and lines with singleton keys.

Answer (score 0):

Just a normal unique sort should work

```
awk '!a[$0]++' test
```